# Visualforce Side Panel

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Can we do a side panel with tabs in Visualforce?  I see `apex:tabPanel` tag that show tabs accross the top of the page, but what about adding the tabs on the left side of the page?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to make stylistic changes by using `styleClass` and css, but since `tabPanels` are (by default) rendered in a whole mess of `<table>` tags, I'm afraid you don't have a way to rearrange the underlying elements.

Comment: Thank you Samuel.  I found some codes online that will just might work.  I think it's as nice as a tab but it will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

So, I try this and it will do for now.`

```
<div style="width:150px;height:310px;border:solid 1px red;background-color:#C0C0C0;float:left"> 
      <apex:commandButton value="Overview" action="{!overview}" style="background:LightBlue;width:149px;height:49px;"/><br/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Read More" action="{!readMore}" style="background:LightBlue;width:149px;height:50px;"/>      
  </div>`
```